# is nginx or haproxy able to do proxy stuff to google.com?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, haproxy

Hi my country blocked google.com anyway I have a virtual machine which is outside the country and have access to google. it has nginx & haproxy installed, based on my limited understanding these reverse proxy can do proxy to internal servers but is there anyway to let them do proxy to google.com directly?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using NGINX or HAPROXY to proxy some URL or google.com what you should do is use your VM as a proxy for the browser. Execute below on your machine

```
$ ssh -D 8123 -f -C -q -N sammy@example.com
```

Explanation of arguments

```
-D: Tells SSH that we want a SOCKS tunnel on the specified port number (you can choose a number between 1025-65536)
-f: Forks the process to the background
-C: Compresses the data before sending it
-q: Uses quiet mode
-N: Tells SSH that no command will be sent once the tunnel is up
```

This will open a socks proxy on `127.0.0.1:8123`, you can set this in your browser and open google through your server.

For more detailed article refer to below

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel